# Is there a particular prefix or suffix used when storing a subscription in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript

Essentially my question is very simple; basically when storing an Observable variable we use the "$" suffix for example like this:

`public value$: Observable<string>;`

But if I wanted to store a subscription such that I can trigger an unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy` for example I was wondering if there was an Angular idiomatic way of naming this variable.

Perhaps like this:
`public value#: Subscription;`

I know that the "#" sign when used as a prefix is used to declare private variables in ECMA Script so I'm not suggesting that the pound sign suffix is the solution it's merely used as a placeholder here to help visualise what I am asking.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I always suffix them with `Subscription`. But that is just an opinionated method.:)

Comment: The question still stands and any recommendation would be appreciated; however, I realised that the problem at hand being "storing a subscription" can likely be avoided as the reason I wanted to do it was to expose the ".unsubscribe". I could instead create a ReplaySubject called something like "this.destroy$" and then use that in my RxJS pipe with a "takeUntil(this.destroy$)" and in my ngOnDestroy I could call ```this.destroy$.next(true); this.destroy$.complete();``` and it would likely solve all my problems. But my question still stands - if we did it the above way, how would we name it?

Comment: Yeah @Silvermind that is the approach I went with as well,.. but I was wondering if there was some other character we could use that would prevent the variable name from including "Subscription" as it is fairly long.